# Assosicated products not showing magento - uploaded by xml - bulk upload extension

Tags: magento, product

I'm using this extension
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-bulk-product-import-export-with-tier-pricing-product-custom-options-configurable-products-bundle-products-grouped-products-downloadable.html

for uploading configurable products on store

Process run successfully without any error

but in configurable products there is not associated products.

any help ?????????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of your excel or xml file field problem
please check

Attributes and Attributes values of configurable products
Check Value of associated field in xml or excel file.
Check other stock or qty field values.

Just Check and Cheers !!!